# How to I install Ghostscript 9.21 with homebrew?

Tags: homebrew

I'm stuck using Ghostscript 9.21 on my project, and homebrew is installing 9.55. How do I install 9.21? I tried `brew install ghostscript@9.21` but the package doesn't have versioning.

I'd like to use https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/f7092d9202dbfbd9ea0ae70064c59e796b81d5df/Formula/ghostscript.rb but when I `brew install https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/f7092d9202dbfbd9ea0ae70064c59e796b81d5df/Formula/ghostscript.rb` I get:

```
/opt/homebrew/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:277:in `load_file': Invalid usage: Installation of ghostscript from a GitHub commit URL is unsupported! `brew extract ghostscript` to a stable tap on GitHub instead. (UsageError)
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to do it with `brew extract` as it says.

Answer (score 1):

`brew extract` was broken, and [a fix](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/pull/12453) has been merged. Now you can extract the formula:

1. Create a Homebrew tap where the formula will be extracted to:

   ```
   brew tap-new $USER/local-tap
   ```
2. Extract Ghostscript 9.21 to your tap:

   ```
   brew extract --version=9.21 ghostscript $USER/local-tap
   ```

However, there are still some changes that must be made to fix the formula:

1. Set the `HOMEBREW_EDITOR` environment variable to your editor of choice. Mine is `code`
2. Run `brew edit ghostscript@9.21`
3. Delete `revision 4` because this is a new formula.
4. The sha256 hashes of the patches are wrong, probably because [`a=patch` adds the Git version at the bottom of the patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60686478/patch-file-includes-the-git-version-at-the-end). Let's change `a=patch` to `a=commitdiff_plain` and blank out `sha256` to get the new hashes later:

   ```rb
       patch do
         url "https://git.ghostscript.com/?p=ghostpdl.git;a=commitdiff_plain;h=4f83478c88"
         sha256 ""
       end

       patch do
         url "https://git.ghostscript.com/?p=ghostpdl.git;a=commitdiff_plain;h=04b37bbce1"
         sha256 ""
       end

       patch do
         url "https://git.ghostscript.com/?p=ghostpdl.git;a=commitdiff_plain;h=57f20719e1"
         sha256 ""
       end
   ```
5. Delete the `devel` block:

   ```
   -  devel do
   -    url "https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/download/gs922rc2/ghostscript-9.22rc2.tar.gz"
   -    sha256 "1861c0cee1e005bd2712873e3058ee1c131c79819625fe479ebcef68e055648e"
   -  end
   ```

   (`devel` was deprecated somewhat recently.)
6. Delete `depends_on :x11 => :optional` (assuming you don't need X11 support)
7. Also delete `if build.without? "x11"` like so:

   ```
   -    args << "--without-x" if build.without? "x11"
   +    args << "--without-x"
   ```

   (`:x11` has been replaced by the `libx11` formula.)
8. Now run `brew install -s ghostscript@9.21` and you'll get the new sha256 hashes mentioned above:

   ```
   $ brew install -s ghostscript@9.21
   ==> Downloading https://git.ghostscript.com/?p=ghostpdl.git;a=commitdiff_plain;h=4f83478c88
   -#O#- #   #                                                                   
   Warning: Cannot verify integrity of '86093339e3f806acdd14f4ba35d2748f1c31cd4f5008d39a4646e9036b5cb767--ghostpdl.git-4f83478c88.patch'.
   For your reference, the checksum is:
     sha256 "fa46ee96c9896a6feb0f23fd4276023477988c904da52e581efbc78c307eb435"
   ```

Finally, your formula should look like [this](https://gist.github.com/FnControlOption/244a8d45f5b806e0ec9a953f4fe36a90).